# How to select Row without key

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

There are many ways to select a row programmatically e.g. by if we know row index, or if we know the Primary-key-like column (column that contain unique value).

Now, when I'm creating my custom control, I wonder is there another way to select row using another way?

Let's say I backup the selected record in each OnSelectionChanged event using variable named BackupRow.

then when I sort the data using columnheader click, in OnSorted I want to select the grid using the BackupRow.

Is something like that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use BackupRow.Index ?

Comment: what do you mean by sorting using backup row? an example would be more helpful to understand.

Comment: the case is I have records: ABCD
current row is: B
then, I reverse sort it become: DCBA
current row is: C

what I want is, current row: still B after sorted

Answer (score 0):

No other method.. For solution to your problem you could.

Backup indices(in an integer list or array), no need to backup complete rows.. if you do need you do it as well. But you need to Backup indices any case.. And select rows form sorted grid on the base of those (backup) indices

Answer (score 0):

if your data count never change and you can exactly know sorting algorithm its possible but not trustful for the true value..

as a pseudo-example : You have rows A-B-C-D and current is B..

if rows sorted ascendant (A to Z or 0 to 100) and then you sorted descendant(Z to A or 100 to 0) then its simply :
suppose your,
total rows = 45;
current row index for ascendant sort = 30;

sort descendant();

your current's new index = (total row - ascendant sorted row index)-1; 
//-1 is for index [0] correction

your current's new index = 45-30 -1;
your current's new index = 14;

And an alternative way :

implement your own sort algorithm and create a delegate / pointer - i can't imagine which can be better right now-

then while each sort operation investigate your selected row and select again..

but as i said these are nost trustful ways..and noone never prefer / suggest..

Another Opinion :

Your question is not clear for me..this opinion is for clearer the possible misunderstood..

if you want "when user selects a row or sorts from-on a column value, the complete row cells get highlighted automatically- shown to user as Selected"

then its under datagridview's SelectionMode Property..

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect;
```